# MySQL: Comments for multiple tables

Tags: mysql, sql, orm

**Disclaimer: I know that this is a common question, but I could not find a satisfying answer as of yet.**

Many of you might know the problem: We have a "comment" table but multiple points where we can attach comments to:

[image]

So, how do we solve this?

### Approach 1 (multiple fks)

We could store multiple foreign keys like this:

[image]

While this works fine with MySQL, it is a bad approach in general, because foreign keys should not contain NULL values.

### Approach 2 (abstraction)

Let's abstract article & blog post:

[image]

While this seems like a better approach, it comes at costs of performance. **Using ORM** we have to fetch a lot of stuff:

We want to select the `article.id`. Therefore we have to fetch `global_id`. Since `global_id` *should* be unidirectional we would have to fetch both `article` and `blog post`, to hydrate the global_id ORM entity.
Instead of one simple

`SELECT id FROM article`

we come up with:

`SELECT global_id.id, article.*, blog_post.* FROM article JOIN global_id ON global_id.id = article.global_id JOIN blog_post ON blog_post.global_id = global_id`

At least this is what happens when using doctrine, which hydrates one-to-one / one-to-many associations immediately.

Of course, we could hack our way into that and use two fields for our `article` and `blog_post` entity like this:

`protected int id;
protected foreign_key global_id;`

But things get really messy from there, especially if we have a UnitOfWork and stuff like that, so that isn't a good solution at all.

### Question

So, how do we do this fast, efficient and beautifully? Or is the solution right up there?

Answer (score 0):

I think the cleanest way is to separate comments by type. I mean create

- article_comment
- blog_comment
- etc.

tables.

Comment: Absolutely not. Let's say you want to add a "timestamp" to your comment. While this would be easy in your business logic, this will be a pain in your database (modifying 10+ tables).

Comment: Generally you are right. And I don't think there is an universal solution. It depends on the requirements. Otherwise it can happen that you have to introduce the timestamp only for one kind of data...

Comment: Sure, but I still think that this isn't the way to go. Let's say we don't only want to have "comments" but also "votes" (on articles, blog posts and comments). You'd have to create multiple comment tables (article_comment, blog_comment) and multiple vote tables (article_vote, blog_vote, blog_comment_vote, article_comment_vote) since the structure completely lacks abstraction.

Comment: Ehh. I missed you asked the question... Probably if you have this kind of constraints then this approach is not appropriate for you...

Comment: Just wanted to point out, that scaling isn't possible with this approach. But thanks for your contribution :)

Answer (score 0):

You can create you table as:
Comment Table

```
- id (PK AU)  
- user_id (int)  
- type_id (int)
- type (enum ['article','blog']  
- content (varchar)
```

This structure help you to retrieve/ update data into table.

Comment: I don't see a foreign key in there?

Comment: Thanks :)
However, I'm not sure performance will be better (since you're not using fks) and I'm not sure if this works with ORM seamlessly (because again, no fks). Retrieving `$article->getComments()` will be a huge pain.

Comment: @machete: i dont think retrieving will be pain as you will add coditioins as what type of comment you want to retrieve like article,blog, etc..

Comment: With custom ORM yes, but the ORM association concept itself isn't made to deal with stuff like this (I think).